# Simple javascript correction (Date / Time)

Tags: javascript, time

Where am I going wrong with this code?

```
var now = Date.now();
var HoursLater = now.addHours(6);
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}

document.write(HoursLater);
```

​

Comment: Whilst I agree with Gung foo I did a fiddle with your code see it here - note that as it currently stands you will ALSO be updating the "now" var as the prototype is operating on "this" too http://jsfiddle.net/gXr9R/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel!

There are good libraries around which will save you alot of time.

look at [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). it already has addHours()!

> ```
> .addHours ( Number hours ) : Date
>
> Adds the specified number of hours to this instance given the number of hours to add. The number can be positive or negative.
> ```

```
// Solution to your problem with date.js ;)
Date.today().addHours(6);

// What date is next thursday?
Date.today().next().thursday();

// Add 3 days to Today
Date.today().add(3).days();
```

Comment: Is there any way to test this with Jsfiddle?

Comment: Now... how would I write out only the hours / minutes in the format:  hh:mm?   Using (Date.today().addHours) certainly didn't do that Tue Oct 23 2012 06:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) =(

Comment: addHours simply returns a date object... (this is the way a date object is being printed) you can use it the way you are already used to.

Comment: I'm not really a javascript developer (actually java is my trade), so I don't really know how to treat what's returned as a string and substring it, I also don't know how to grab just the date in hours / minutes.

Comment: again.. addHours() returns a date OBJECT it is NOT a string, only displayed to you like that for your convenience. just use getHours() and getMintues()...

Comment: At the risk of hand-holding on this one, I am not able to pass the hours I need added to do this.  <script>document.write(Date.today().gethours(+6.0)+ getMinutes());</script> is my code for this

Answer (score 2):

Your prototype method `addHours` is defined on the Date() object, not on Date.now().

Just modify your first line to `var Now = new Date();`

Also move the prototype method definition for `addHours` to the top(due to the order of execution of the previous 2 statements).

http://jsfiddle.net/ATUpF/